# How do I fix a StackOverflowError on Struts DispatchAction?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

Here's the situation:
I practiced creating a mini blog application. I used Strut's EventDispatchAction to handle all post related methods like updating and listing posts.

I have an update() method (http://mywebsite/post?update) that updates the database and then if it's successful it forwards to the same action class but I used a different method to handle it, the list() method (http://mywebsite/post?list) which lists all the posts of the current user. The problem is it doesn't work and throws up a:

> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>
> The server side component of the HTTP
>   Monitor has detected a
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError. This
>   happens when there is an infinite loop
>   in the web module. Correct the cause
>   of the infinite loop before running
>   the web module again.

Do you guys have any idea on how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I solved it guys. I just need to put value in the parameter of my forward, in my case I have to do: post?list=list instead of just post?list (the normal way). The method is ignored I guess if it doesn't have a value. It's really weird why Struts is behaving like this. Maybe someone can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

Is there no more exception information, like a stack trace?

Do you have unit tests for the `list()` method? A stack overflow is almost always caused by a recursive method (or cycle of methods) but without any more information about the stack trace, it's very hard to diagnose it further.

If you can't get a full stack trace after the exception has been thrown, you might want to add more logging into `list()` and the methods it calls, to show you where the recursion is occurring.

EDIT: Okay, looking at the stack trace it looks like you've got one action forwarding either to itself, or to another action which forwards back to the first one. It looks like *your code* isn't involved, given that it doesn't appear in the stack trace. Check your Struts config for cycles.

The other interesting bit of the stack trace is "org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter" - is this application running in your IDE? Does it still fail if you run it *not* in the IDE?

Comment: Here's the stack trace: http://pastebin.com/m6a785f4f

On an unrelated note, I saw your name Jon on the ads here at SO. Cool :D

Comment: Here's the update method's forward: <forward name="updatePostSuccess" path="/post.do?list"/>

It seems that it's not executing the list() method (/post.do?list) as it should. I'll try to run it out of Netbeans.

Comment: Hi guys, it still produces the same errors when I ran it outside of Netbeans.